# Convert datetime format to java

Tags: java

How can I convert this format of date in Java?

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString ("u").Replace ('Z', ' ') ,
```

Here is an example how it is

```
"<FechaDesde>"+DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString ("u").Replace ('Z', ' ')+"</FechaDesde>" +
```

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: I updated my question, please review it above please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// new Calendar represents current time
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// subtract five days
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);

// specify format required
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS); // or whatever format you want

// format the date and add the prefix and suffix
String formattedDate = "<FechaDesde>" + sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + "</FechaDesde>";
```